# Integral of a product with any continuous function which has integral 0 is equal to 0

Tags: lebesgue-integral

Let $g:[0,1]\to\mathbb{R}$ be bounded and measurable.
For every continuous function $f$ with $\int_0^1f(x)dx=0$, $\int_0^1f(x)g(x)dx=0$ holds.

I want to prove that $g$ is a constant function on almost everywhere.

I approached in various way:

1. I defined a function $h(c)=m(\{x\ \vert\ \vert g(x)-c\vert>0\})$ and tried to prove the existence of a root, but it was difficult to approach.
2. I consider new function $g_0=g+\vert\vert g\vert\vert_\infty$ and I found that I can assume $g$ be positive because $g_0$ satisfies all the properties of $g$ what I need.
3. Since $[0,1]$ is closed and $f$ is continuous, we can know that $f$ is bounded on $[0,1]$. So, we can define $f_0$ in the analogous sense with what I done to $g$.

But I can not do further. Please give me a hint or the concepts I should know. Any advice is welcome. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Hint: What is $\int_0^1 f(x) g(x)\; dx$ when $f$ is an arbitrary continuous function?

Comment: Hmm... After thinking, I have only that the integral is bounded by $M\int_0^1g$.

Comment: I might(?) apply the mean value theorem.

Comment: I have an uniform continuity of $f$ I think.

Comment: Further hint: find $c$ so that $\int_0^1 (f(x) -c)\; dx = 0$.

Comment: Isn't $c=0$ since $\int f=0$ for all $f$?

Comment: No.  $\int f = 0$ only for the $f$ in the hypothesis.

Comment: Then, for any measurable function $f$, $c$ would be $\int_0^1 f(x)dx$.

Comment: Yes, it would.  So what does that say about $\int_0^1 f(x) g(x)\; dx$?

Comment: Well, as you pointed out, I would have $\int_0^1(f(x)g(x)-(\int_0^1f(y)g(y)dy))dx=0$.

Comment: But, I don't get the procedure what I should do yet.

Comment: Further, $\int_0^1\int_0^1(f(x)g(x)-f(y)g(y))dxdy=0$.

Comment: No, that's not not what I mean.  With $c = \int_0^1 f(x)\; dx$ you would have $\int_0^1 f(x) g(x)\; dx = \int_0^1 (f(x) - c) g(x)\; dx + \int_0^1 c g(x)\; dx = ...$

Comment: Yes, but does it have any useful information? $c$ would be zero by the condition if $f$ is continuous.

Comment: No, $c = \int_0^1 f(x)\; dx$.  Why would that be $0$ if $f$ is continuous?  And yes, it does have useful information: it identifies what linear functional on $C[0,1]$ corresponds to $g$.

Comment: Oh, I misunderstanded the condition I have. Integral 0 does not hold for any continuous function! It says just those functions then $\int fg=0$. My mistake.

Comment: So do you mean the linear functional $L(f)=\int(f-c_f)g+c_f\int g$? This is a linear functional obviously.

Comment: Yes, and one of these terms is $0$...